# Heavy Load C# Application Freezes when Mouse Event is Activated

Tags: c#, events, timer, freeze

My C# application has a timer that triggers an event every 100 milliseconds.  Inside this event there is a receive handler for bus traffic that loops continuously until the receive buffer is empty, or another 100 milliseconds has elapsed.  This works fine until I try to use one of the other controls in my application at run time.  Then the application freezes.  Does anybody have any ideas how I may partition my application (or otherwise modify it), so that when I try to use a control, the background event (tied to the timer) can continue running and not stall the application?  I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) (or an equivalent construct) for the receive handler. That way it will run in a different thread and the form will be able to respond timely, and you won't need a timer in the loop.